# CakePHP advanced routing

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, slug

How do I create URLs like this (English as default):

For action `index` in Categories controller:

- /categories
- /en/categories
- /de/categories
- ...

for action `view` in Categories controller:

- /categories/englishslug
- /de/categories/deutshslug

Answer (score 1):

What's missing from the article is the useful `persist` feature in available in the [Router::connect()](http://api13.cakephp.org/file/cake/libs/router.php#method-Routerconnect).
Which will add the language parameter to all generated urls.

**Example route:**

```
Router::connect(
  '/:language/:controller',
  array(),
  array('language' => '[a-z]{2}', 'persist' => array('language'))
);
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}', 'persist' => array('language')));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what custom routes in CakePHP are made for. You can define your own router class that handles all that logic for you and mitigates everything before running through the dispatcher. I recently did exactly what you're looking to do by referencing this blog post from Mark Story himself: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp